# Positioning of drawn animals in use of the tikzling package

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to add absolute position of the animals when the animals of the tikzling package are loaded. Something like this:

```
\draw(1.5,.5) node {\bear};
```

But unfortunately, this causes an error.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usepackage{tikzlings-marmots}
\usepackage{tikzlings-bears}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw(0,0) grid(9,4);
\bear
%\draw(2.5,.5)node {\bear};
\marmot at (3,1.5);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It that really standard indentation? That includes all the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `xshift` and `yshift` to your animal.

[image: tikzlings animals]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usepackage{tikzlings-marmots}
\usepackage{tikzlings-bears}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw(0,0) grid(9,4);
\bear[xshift=5cm,yshift=2.5cm];
\marmot[xshift=3cm];
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the tikzlings as pic and so place them on a path:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usepackage{tikzlings-marmots}
\usepackage{tikzlings-bears,bearwear}
\tikzset{bear/.pic={\bear\bearwear}}
\tikzset{mole/.pic={\moles}}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw(0,0) grid(9,4);
\draw(0,0) --++(0.5,0.5)pic{bear}--++(1,1) pic{bear}--++(1,1)pic{mole};
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is nice use of pic for that package. I think that kind of thing `\tikzset{bear/.pic={\bear\bearwear}}
\tikzset{mole/.pic={\moles}}` should be available in the package

Answer (score 4):

You can save bear drawing in a box then use it inside a node

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usepackage{tikzlings-marmots}
\usepackage{tikzlings-bears}

\newbox\bearbox

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\savebox{\bearbox}{\bear}
\draw(0,0) grid(9,4);
\bear
\draw(2.5,.5) node {\usebox{\bearbox}};
\marmot at (3,1.5);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```